# How to batch rename files to random characters?

Tags: macos, mac

I have a lot of photos with me that I want to rename. I want them to be 10 random characters. Is there a way to do it?

I am running macOS Sierra.

I didn't try anything yet.

I would prefer a free solution to this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following script assumes that the photos to be renamed are in your Pictures folder. This will rename every file in your Pictures folder to a 10 character random string of letters and numbers while keeping the file extensions intact.

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=({a..z} {A..Z} {0..9})

function random_string {
  local count=$1
  local output=
  while ((count--)); do
    output+=${chars[$((RANDOM % ${#chars[@]}))]}
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$output"
}

for file in ~/Pictures/*; do
  ext=$(echo ${file} | sed 's,^.*\(\.[^\.]*$\),\1,')
  mv "$file" ~/Pictures/"$(random_string 10)"${ext}
done
```

If the files to be renamed are not in your Pictures folder then edit `~/Pictures` accordingly. The `~` is simply a shortcut for the users home directory. So `~/Pictures` = `/Users/YourUsername/Pictures`. Note that the `*` tells the script to match any file found in `~/Pictures`. Also note that you can change the number of characters generated by changing the number `10` of `(rand_string 10)`to any number you like.

- Copy and paste this into a **plain text** file and name it something like: rename_pics.sh
- Open your Terminal (use spotlight to find it if you don't know it's location)
- In your Terminal type `chmod 755 rename_pics.sh` and press Enter
- Then type `./rename_pics.sh` in your terminal and press Enter to run the script.

Comment: By the way, is there a way I can rename without changing the extension? I mean right now I have three different scripts to rename the jpg, png and mp4 files. First, I'll place only jpg files on the Desktop then run the jpg script on the desktop and then move the files to another folder. I'll do the same process for png and mp4 files. It would be better if the script renamed all the files without changing it's extension.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Thanks for the `sed` magic. I have incorporated this into the answer.

Comment: What does `local c=$1` do?

Comment: @samurai_jane `local c=$1` is setting a local variable `c` to the first positional parameter `$1` passed into the function. What that means is when you invoke the function like this `rand_string 10`, the `10` is set to the variable `c` which determines the length of the generated random string. `rand_string 34` would generate a random string with 34 characters. I should probably use better variable names :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this into a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"
for i in ./*; do
    mv "$i" $((RANDOM * 32768 + RANDOM))
done
```

Run the following command to make the file executable (assuming you've saved the file as `randomlyrename`):

```
chmod 755 randomlyrename
```

And run the file:

```
./randomlyrename /path/to/folder/containing/things-to-rename
```

Bear in mind that it'll rename *everything* in the directory it's provided to a string of random numbers ten digits long.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry your script removed all the file extensions. Anyway, I've already found my answer from another user and I've accepted it. Thank you so much for taking the time out to help me :) I really appreciate it :)