# Adding random suffixes to filenames

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, automator

I would like to change the filename of a lot of files by adding a random suffix to the existing filenames.

I have tried to change [this code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255900/how-to-batch-rename-files-to-random-characters?newreg=2a7f94f699c747f8824acbd96904f75e) (changes the filename instead of adding a suffix) but with no succes.

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=( {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} )

function rand_string {
    local c=$1 ret=
    while((c--)); do
        ret+=${chars[$((RANDOM%${#chars[@]}))]}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ret"
}

for file in ~/Desktop/test/*; do
    ext=$(echo ${file} | sed 's,^.*(\.[^\.]*$),\1,')
    mv "$file" ~/Desktop/test/"$file$(rand_string 10)"${ext}
done
```

A command line or automator solution would be preferable

Comment: What exactly have you tried, can you add the script you have so far?

Comment: currently I have changed the last line with an extra variable but I got an error

Comment: #!/bin/bash

chars=( {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} )

function rand_string {
    local c=$1 ret=
    while((c--)); do
        ret+=${chars[$((RANDOM%${#chars[@]}))]}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ret"
}

for file in ~/Desktop/test/*
do
    ext=$(echo ${file} | sed 's,^.*\(\.[^\.]*$\),\1,')
    mv "$file" ~/Desktop/test/"$file$(rand_string 10)"${ext}
done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to append a randomized string the `for` loop is rather simple:

```
cd ~/Desktop/test/
for file in *; do
    suffix="${file##.*}"
    base="${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "$base.$(rand_string 10).$suffix"
done
```

Change the `10` to the number of random characters you want to add.

Comment: Tnx Patrix for your answer. The script is working but now the suffix is added after the file extension. Clearly I am not good at changing code but do you see a way to add the suffix after the filename but before the file extension ?

Comment: @El-Ekim Please make sure that your question represents all the facts. In this case it would have helped to have some clear before/after examples of filenames.

Comment: You are right Patrix. I should have given an example of the filename conversion.
When I use your for-loop I get an error saying : 
mv: rename /Users/Ekim/Desktop/test/xmas_candles.jpg to /Users/Ekim/Desktop/test/xmas_candles.HF8ohLw0Gl./Users/Ekim/Desktop/test/xmas_candles.jpg: No such file or directory 

Thank you so much for taking the time out to help me.

Comment: @El-Ekim Ah, it only works in the current directory, so there is a `cd` required. And from looking at your error you might have a typo somewhere as well.

Comment: excellent, it works great ! :) tnx for you time